# Expand image without smoothing

Tags: html, image

Is it somehow possible to enlarge an img-element, so that it still looks "pixelated"? As you can see in this sample ( http://jsfiddle.net/4qgSc/ ) all browsers I've tested use some "smoothing"-effect. Redrawing it in a canvas is not a possible solution, since i want to animate the enlargement.

Edit:
For now using a class with the following properties:

```
image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
```

achvies the closes result. It works in all browsers except Chrome (16.0.912.75 m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the CSS [image rendering property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Image-rendering)

http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/4qgSc/5/

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I'm looking for! Except, that it doesn't seem to work under Opera, Safari & Chrome? ... Any css equivalent for one of these browsers?

Comment: "image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;" does the job for Opera - even though they say "Currently optimizeSpeed and -moz-crisp-edges are equal, both result in nearest neighbor resampling."... what's actually wrong.

But still no success with Chrome and Safari.

Comment: At this time I think you're out of luck. For Chrome, I found this: http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_image_zoom.html

Comment: Too bad... so for now I think Chrome/Safari users are out of luck. Will it maybe be supportet in later versions? For now the solution is perfekt. Resizing via canvas is - as I already told - way too slow for my use case.

Answer (score -2):

One possible solution would be to expand all your images ( http://jsfiddle.net/4qgSc/1/ ). Your images can bes easily transformed using actions (macros) in Photoshop or other image-editing software using "nearest neighbor" mode:

[image]

Comment: I want to keep the possibility to stepless zoom into the images, so there would be almost infinite possibilities and the client would need to download all the zoomsteps.

Comment: what? No, you just need a big one and that would be enough.

Comment: Ok... Sure, you're right. But since my images already have a size of about 4000², enlarging them 25.000% wouldn't be too nice for the traffic.